# Создать Базу Данных в JS, где будут храниться ссылки на веб-страницы, которые будет вытягивать HTML из БД

Tags: javascript, база-данных

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что часто одна и та же ссылка фигурирует в разных местах нашего учебного сайта: в статьях, в описании под видео или например в меню, которое я слепил не знаю как, но слепил - [**`ПРИМЕР ЗДЕСЬ`**](https://jsfiddle.net/y7wt2kvg/2/). И бывают случаи, что контент устаревает и его заменяют новым, т.е. страница создается новая, ссылка соответственно меняется, а старое убирается в архив. Или надо повторить в нескольких местах одну и ту же ссылку, как в [**`пример в меню`**](https://jsfiddle.net/y7wt2kvg/2/). Так вот,
хотелось бы иметь базу данных с ссылками, куда можно будет обращаться HTML страницам с помощью ID, и когда вдруг надо будет изменить ссылку, поменять ее в БД, чтобы на всех других страницах, где она живет, автоматически обновилась, а не вспоминать, где еще поменять. Вопрос, возможно ли такое сделать на js? Как? И смогу ли я со знаниями HTML и CSS это повторить?

Мне надо, чтобы в HTML тегу приписывалось только ID(ну как пример, может как-то по другому это делается), а уже название ссылки и сама ссылка лежали в js.

Буду признателен любой помощи, разъяснению, примера или ткните в какой-нибудь источник.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let s = [['#id_a1','https://#','Основы / общие материалы'],
          ['#id_a2','https://#','Вебинары']];
for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
    for (let f=0; f<document.querySelectorAll(s[i][0]).length; f++) {
      document.querySelectorAll(s[i][0])[f].href = s[i][1];
      document.querySelectorAll(s[i][0])[f].innerHTML = (s[i][2]);
    }
}
```

```html
<a id="id_a1" href=""></a><br>
<a id="id_a2" href=""></a><br>
<a id="id_a2" href=""></a>
```